# RemoteCertificateValidationCallback usage

Tags: c#, security, ssl

In .NET Core 2.1 you can set a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` handler to verify a server's TLS certificate. The callback signature is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=netcore-2.1) but it is unclear how to use it. There is an `SslPolicyErrors` enum that provides values for *some* potential verification errors but not all. For example, what will be the error if the certificate is expired? Also, what additional checks would the default implementation perform, and do they still apply when I use my callback?

I'd like to change the verification in two ways:

1. If the certificate would normally be valid, I want to restrict the certificate, any chain or CA cert to a specified hash. So I can limit the certificates or CA used by the server. SSL proxys would be detected in this case.
2. If the certificate or CA is self-signed and would normally not be accepted, I want to accept it anyway if the hash matches. In this case, the `SslPolicyErrors` probably comes with a value other than `None`.

In any case, the certificate name and validity time must still be correct. I'm not going to override these. I've only got a web server with a wrong certificate name here for testing (sets `SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`), but none with an expired certificate.

How would this be done in C#?

This is the bare skeleton method:

```
private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return certificate.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256) == "12345...";
}
```

I'm not sure yet about the hash algorithm. The default SHA-1 is probably not suitable anymore and it might not even exist. I'll have to play more when the basics are done.

Comment: The callback comes after all default checks and provide you with their result in `sslPolicyErrors`. In your callback you are now free to do whatever, maybe considering the errors, maybe not. Just return true or false depending on your own analysis of the situation.